# vuex.esm.js:460 [vuex] unknown mutation type: removeProductFromCart

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

I am trying to delete the product from the cart but I am getting unknown mutation type: removeProductFromCart error.

I am calling this function in my Cart component to delete the item when click the button and dispatch the store:

```
methods: {
    removeFromCart(id) {
        cartHelper.removeFromCart(id, () => {
            this.$store.dispatch('removeProductFromCart', id)
        });
    },
},
```

And my action:

```
export const removeProductFromCart = ({ commit }, id) => {
    commit('REMOVE_PRODUCT_FROM_CART', id);
}
```

And my mutation:

```
export const REMOVE_PRODUCT_FROM_CART = (state, id) => {
    state.cart = state.cart.filter(item => {
        return item.id !== id;
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're calling removeProductFromCart correctly? Is it directly in the root of your store folder? If not, you'll probably need to call it using `this.$store.dispatch('foldername/removeProductFromCart', id)`